# How to retrieve the directory in which the current class/dll is located in C#?

Tags: c#

One of my classes, to execute some instructions needs to know its location (as an absolute path). I was using a naive Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), until I noticed that things get messed up when the user is actually not executing from the directory where the class is sitting.

How can I get that ? So far my googling is unfructuous... :(

PS : I intend to release this class as a DLL, no COM or anything fancy, just a basic DLL. Will that change any rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
string path = GetType().Assembly.GetModules(false)[0].FullyQualifiedName;
```

(Assuming you only have one module, which is likely.)

Answer (score 5):

```
string path = typeof(YourClass).Assembly.Location; 
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it from Assembly

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```